# Need to get return vaue from thread with this coding style

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, begininvoke

my tests show that following code queues 10 theads and runs 3 of them at same time. It's okay. but I cannot get return value from class.

Also Finalize event never fires until I terminate program. Its strange because I hoped then thread end, it automatically destroys itself. but is not.

I see that I need to use delegate function to achieve this but I could not succeed using delegate with this queue sample.

can anyone help me to get return value inside callback function please ? I'm going crazy and obviously my knowledge is not enough for that.

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Threading
Public Class Form1
    Private tasks As New Queue(Of Action)
    Private RunningThread As Integer
    Private Lock As New Object
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnButton1.Click
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 1 To 10
            Dim w As New Work()
            w.Data = i
            Dim Task As New Action(AddressOf w.DoWork)
            If RunningThread < 3 Then
                Task.BeginInvoke(AddressOf Callback, Nothing)
                Threading.Interlocked.Increment(RunningThread)
                Console.WriteLine(i.ToString & " basladi")
            Else
                Console.WriteLine(i.ToString & " bekliyor")
                SyncLock (Lock)
                    tasks.Enqueue(Task)
                End SyncLock
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
    Private Sub Callback(ByVal o As Object)
        If tasks.Count > 0 Then
            Dim Task As Action
            SyncLock (Lock)
                Task = tasks.Dequeue
            End SyncLock
            Task.BeginInvoke(AddressOf Callback, Nothing)
        Else
            Threading.Interlocked.Decrement(RunningThread)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

and this is the very simple class I call.

```
Public Class Work
    Public Data As Integer
    Public Function DoWork() As String
        Console.WriteLine(Data.ToString & " inside class")
        Thread.Sleep(1000)
        Return Data.ToString & " output parameter"
    End Function
    Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()
        Console.WriteLine(Data.ToString & " this code never runs until form close.")
        MyBase.Finalize()
    End Sub
End Class
```

note: this is currently working code.

Comment: A finalizer is pretty much never the correct solution to any question (except if the question happens to be "how can I get a non deterministic broken program in one easy step?" Then it's great). There's no guarantee that it ever runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Work.Finalize does not run until termination because you are not destroying the local variable `w` when you are done with it.  Finalize is managed by the garbage collector during deallocation of a variable.  What are you trying to accomplish with it? Perhaps you should be using some other solution.
2. Your code in `Button1_Click` does not catch the return from `Work.DoWork`.  Instead of Action, I used Tasks.Task(Of String) and put them all into 1 list for processing.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 10
        Dim w As New Work()
        w.Data = i
        Dim t = Tasks.Task(Of String).Factory.StartNew(AddressOf w.DoWork)
        RunningTasks.Add(t)
    Next

    i = 0
    For Each t In RunningTasks
        i = i + 1
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Task {0} completed with value: {1}", i, t.Result))
    Next
End Sub
```

Output:

```
1 inside class
3 inside class
4 inside class
2 inside class
5 inside class
7 inside class
8 inside class
6 inside class
9 inside class
Task 1 completed with value: 1 output parameter
10 inside class
Task 2 completed with value: 2 output parameter
Task 3 completed with value: 3 output parameter
Task 4 completed with value: 4 output parameter
Task 5 completed with value: 5 output parameter
Task 6 completed with value: 6 output parameter
Task 7 completed with value: 7 output parameter
Task 8 completed with value: 8 output parameter
Task 9 completed with value: 9 output parameter
Task 10 completed with value: 10 output parameter
```

You could also use Action(Of String) and change your BeginInvoke to:
`task.BeginInvoke(outputVariable, AddressOf Callback, Nothing)`

Since I am not sure what you want to do with the output so I do not know how to handle it in the call back.

Comment: Thanks but as I see your code runs 10 tasks at once. I need to queue them. my problem is send them to queue (as my example code) and meantime get value from callback function from each thread.

Finalize event won't work, yes, because I don't destroy them but in this scenario I don't know how to destroy them.

Comment: Have you considered using the ThreadPool class? Do you need to execute the code in the Finalize or can you let it happen automatically?  Can you achieve this in some other way (like calling a new function DoFinalWork when needed)?

Comment: I have also used the SmartThreadPool in another project.  It manages all of your queuing needs pretty well; however, the project may be dead: https://smartthreadpool.codeplex.com/